# How to set the path of a cookie using Firefox Web Developer toolbar?

Tags: firefox, cookies, firefox-developer-tools

I need to set a cookie manually to test the login page of my website. However, I am not sure how to set the path option. I keep getting a "Too many arguments" warning. Does anyone know to do it with the **Firefox Web Developer toolbar**? Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: FWIW, it took me a bit to realize that the Web Developer Toolbar command-line is different from the Console command-line under the Tools area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it says "[options]", you're supposed so enter something like `--switch`. Once you hit the `-`, you'll normally get auto-completion suggestions for all available options.

To answer your particular question:

```
cookie set aName aValue --path /aPath
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out yesterday after trying all the keys on my keyboard. Do you happen to know why setting a cookie for multiple subdomains using `--domain .mysite.com` will generate a `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE`?